# How to populate the retrieved values from DB in ListBox using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

Can anyone help me how to populate the retrieved values in ListBoxFor. I tried this but doesn't works.

Code in Model:-

```
public List<SelectListItem> SafetyRepresentataives { get; set; }
public List<string> BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative { get; set; }
```

Code in Controller:=

```
var site = entityDB.ClientBusinessUnitSites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ClientBusinessUnitSiteId == 
siteId);
var siteRepresentatives = from representatives in entityDB.ClientBusinessUnitSiteRepresentatives
                                      where representatives.ClientBUSiteID == siteId
                                      select representatives;

local.SafetyRepresentataives = (from o in entityDB.SystemUsersOrganizations.ToList()
                                           from c in entityDB.Contact.ToList()
                                           where o.OrganizationId == clientId && c.UserId == 
                                            o.UserId
                                           select new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Text = c.FirstName + "," + c.LastName,
                                               Value = c.UserId.ToString()
                                           }).ToList();
foreach (var representative in siteRepresentatives)
            {   
local.BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative.Add(representative.SafetyRepresentative.ToString());
            }
```

Code in View:-

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative, new 
MultiSelectList(Model.SafetyRepresentataives,"Value","Text"))
```

I have retrieved the values from DB as shown above. But I am unable to link these retrieved values to ListBox so as to populate them. How to do this?? Help me out please!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding a default list helped me in resolving my issue. Here is the solution.

```
local.BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative = new List<string>();
            foreach (var representative in siteRepresentatives)
            {

local.BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative.Add(representative.SafetyRepresentative.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this link should help you

```
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
```

In the sample they pass the combobox items in the viewbag.

I recomend you use a jquery plugin like autocomplete or typeahead from twitter bootstrap. So you can load asynchronously the elements.